# What is a good word processor that supports markdown?

Tags: text-editors, markdown, word-processing, writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any text editors which are Markdown aware and provide spell checking features?](https://superuser.com/questions/235519/are-there-any-text-editors-which-are-markdown-aware-and-provide-spell-checking-fe)

I love markdown and hate, hate, hate MS Word. For me, markdown it is a perfect way to write: concentrate in structure and content first, and style the whole thing when you are done. You  forget about all the MS Word crazyness, and have a portable text that can be styled with css when published in different blogs, websites, etc. Good stuff.

I would love a text processor that allows me to write in markdown format, and apply styles to the text later, (sorta like with CSS)

Bonus points if it supports saving to .doc too.

Extra bonus points if it supports both osx and windows.

Comment: On OS X you should try [TextMate](http://macromates.com) and its MultiMarkdown/Markdown bundles. No .doc (obviously), but export to pdf/html/latex.

Comment: I use Textmate and love it, but I am looking for something oriented to writing, not coding.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/235519/are-there-any-text-editors-which-are-markdown-aware-and-provide-spell-checking-fe) out.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has a markdown mode http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode, the preview is not immediate, you hit a key and it launches the web browser and shows you the html.

Emacs runs on windows, Macs and Linux etc.

However Emacs does have a learning curve, but once you get into it you won't use anything else ;)